# Php Javascript writing the content of document.write into a variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm in front of this problem that I can't figure out how to solve properly.

I'm using a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gta4.it/stat/view_stats.js.php?mode=0">  </script>
```

that has as output a single `document.write`:

```
document.write('11');
```

And so the number is displayed using JavaScript.
What I want to do is to get the content of this `document.write` and write it into a variable, JavaScript or PHP, in another server.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That script is just outputting a small JavaScript snippet - You don't need to actually let it execute in the browser if you want to capture its result in PHP:

```
// Assuming you have [allow_url_fopen][1] enabled
$js = file_get_contents( 'http://www.gta4.it/stat/view_stats.js.php?mode=0');
$value = trim( str_replace( array( "document.write('", "');"), '', $js));
echo $value; // Outputs 9, the current value of the JS
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/STKluU)

Of course, if you're looking for a more robust solution that would still work if the JS snippet changes (introduces whitespace, changes quotation types, etc), you can use a regex to extract the number from the snippet. Something like this should work:

```
$js = file_get_contents( 'http://www.gta4.it/stat/view_stats.js.php?mode=0');
$value = preg_replace('/^\s*document\.write\(\s*[\'"](\d*)[\'"]\s*\)\s*;\s*$/im', '$1', $js);
echo $value; // Outputs 11, the now current value of the JS
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/a3FVDy)

If, for some reason, you want / need to let it execute in a browser before capturing the value, you can do something like this, although I'm sure it's not standards-compliant and seems pretty hackish.

1. Wrap the `<script>` tag in a container, perhaps a `<span>` or `<div>`
2. Use JS to get the contents of the container.
3. Use AJAX to send the result to a server.

Sample (untested):

```
<div id="stats_container">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gta4.it/stat/view_stats.js.php?mode=0">  </script>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var value = document.getElementById( 'stats_container').innerHTML;
    alert( value); // Here you would use AJAX to send the value to a server
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Like any JavaScript function, you can can hijack `document.write` and replace it with your own function:

```
<script>
    var oldWrite = document.write; // Save original function.
    var myValue = "";
    document.write = function(str) {myValue += str;}; // Overwrite function.
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gta4.it/stat/view_stats.js.php?mode=0">  </script>
<script>
    document.write = oldWrite; // Restore old function.
    alert(myValue);
</script>
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/qwef4/

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think the hijack of Brian Nickel is the best solution in the case you want it in JS. If this is not a solution for you, you can always try my solution below. Of course for server side retrieval, you can still use things like file_get_contents.

The only (dirty) thing that comes into my mind is that you use an iframe to load a page that includes the script you mention. You can than load the iframe in your actual page and grab whatver is in the iframe into a variable, like so:

```
$content = getContentFromIframe("something");

function getContentFromIframe(iFrameId){
    var myFrame = document.getElementById(iFrameId);
    return myFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
}
```

Of course, after retrieval of the data you can remove the iFrame from your page using some scripting. But I assume you hide it using some styling anyway.

If you want to value to be in a server side language like PHP you can just get the contents of the file by calling the file through [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for example.

Comment: This will only work if your page is in the same domain as the page in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in javascript/html

```
<span id="getvar" style="display: none;">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gta4.it/stat/view_stats.js.php?mode=0">  </script>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
var getvar = document.getElementById('getvar');
var stat = parseInt(getvar.innerText || getvar.textContent);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I tested it and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Baszz, `document.write` only clears page content if it is called after the DOM finishes loading.  Prior to that point, it just appends the content in the exact point of insertion and acts as if it was part of the physical file.  Only after page load (timeouts, events, AJAX), is `document.write(foobar)` equivalent to `document.open();document.write(foobar)`.